# Does Linkify work for TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, linkify

I have this code working for my method that calls an EditText, I tried to use the same code for a TextView but it does not work. The text does not turn into a hyperlink like it does in EditText, does anybody know why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_view);
    // make sure that setText call comes BEFORE Linkify.addLinks call
    tv.setText(tv.getText().toString());
    Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
}}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_lbl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:text="Link" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="google.com" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This will work fine in EditText, i just need help doing the same thing in TextView

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have clickable span and set the text with the clikable span. You can have custom color for the clickabke span. When you click on the text in textview it displays a toast.

```
String title="hello";
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(title);
    ss1.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(title), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText(ss1);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

MyClickableSpan

```
   class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{     
   String clicked;
   public MyClickableSpan(String string)  
   {
    super();
    clicked =string;
   }
   public void onClick(View tv) 
   {
     // onclick of text in textview do something 
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,clicked ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //display a toast 
   }
   public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
   {
     ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);//set text color 
     ds.setUnderlineText(true); // set to false to remove underline
   }
  }
```

Resulting Snap Shot

[image]

EDIT:

Open a browser with the url on click on text in textview. You can also pass the url to a activity. Retrieve the url and load the url in webview.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

public void onClick(View tv) {
//do something

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,clicked ,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   String url = "http://www.example.com";
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
}


                OR
```

In onClick()

```
   Intent t= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
   t.putExtra("key","http://www.google.com");
   startActivity(t);
```

second.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <WebView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/wv"></WebView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Then in SecondActivty

public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        wv.loadUrl(extras.getString("key"));
    }   
} 
 }
```

Comment: if i put a website does it load it?

Comment: @lucas you need to handle that in onClick(). Have a webview and load the url in onClick() or start a new activity whihc loads a webview with the url

Answer (score 2):

Just try below code. It works fine for me.

```
TextView tv = ....
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

String content = tv.getText().toString();
List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    String urlStr = m.group();
    links.add(urlStr);
}

SpannableString f = new SpannableString(content);

for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    final String url = links.get(i);

    f.setSpan(new InternalURLSpan(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context ctx = v.getContext();
            String urlToOpen = url;
            if (!urlToOpen.startsWith("http://") || !urlToOpen.startsWith("https://"))
                urlToOpen = "http://" + urlToOpen;
            openURLInBrowser(urlToOpen, ctx);
        }
    }), content.indexOf(url), content.indexOf(url) + url.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

tv.setText(f);
```

Comment: Vmerror i am having trouble implementing your code, could you help me out? I am a beginner with android